# SQL - Separate string into columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, csv

I am bulk inserting a csv file into SQL Server 2012. The data is currently `|` pipe delimited as one long string for each row. I'd like to separate the data into the different columns at each pipe.

Here is how the data looks as its imported:

```
ID|ID2|Person|Person2|City|State
"1"|"ABC"|"Joe"|"Ben"|"Boston"|"MA"
"2"|"ABD"|"Jack"|"Tim"|"Nashua"|"NH"
"3"|"ADC"|"John"|"Mark"|"Hartford"|"CT"
```

I'd liek to separate the data into the columns at each pipe:

```
ID  ID2 Person  Person2 City    State
1   ABC  Joe     Ben    Boston   MA
2   ABD  Jack    Tim    Nashua   NH
3   AFC  John    Mark   Hartford CT
```

I'm finding it difficult to use `charindex and substring functions` because of the number of columns of the data also I've tried to use `ParseName` since that is a 2012 function but thats not working either as all the columns come out as NULL with `ParseName`

The file contains about 300k rows and I've found a solution using xmlname but it is very slow. ie: takes a minute to separate the data.

Here's the slow xml solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(iddata varchar(200))

DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 100000 
BEGIN

SET @i = @i + 1

INSERT INTO #tbl(iddata)
SELECT '"1"|"ABC"|"Joe"|"Ben"|"Boston"|"MA"'
UNION ALL
SELECT '"2"|"ABD"|"Jack"|"Tim"|"Nashua"|"NH"'
UNION ALL
SELECT '"3"|"AFC"|"John"|"Mark"|"Hartford"|"CT"'


END


;WITH XMLData 
AS
(
    SELECT idData,
    CONVERT(XML,'<IDs><id>'  
    + REPLACE(iddata,'|', '</id><id>') + '</id></IDs>') AS xmlname
      FROM (
            SELECT REPLACE(iddata,'"','') as iddata
            FROM #tbl
            )x
)

 SELECT xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[1]','varchar(100)') AS ID,
       xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[2]','varchar(100)') AS ID2,
       xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[3]','varchar(100)') AS Person,
       xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[4]','varchar(100)') AS Person2,
       xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[5]','varchar(100)') AS City,
       xmlname.value('/IDs[1]/id[6]','varchar(100)') AS State
 FROM XMLData
```

Comment: This questions contains everything a good question needs: copy'n'pasteable test data, input, expected output, own attempt and a clear question. Upvote from my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it for you.

```
    CREATE TABLE #Import (
            ID NVARCHAR(MAX),
            ID2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Person NVARCHAR(MAX),
            Person2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
            City NVARCHAR(MAX),
            State NVARCHAR(MAX))

        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

        BULK INSERT #Import
        FROM 'C:\MyFile.csv'
        WITH
        (
            FIRSTROW = 2,
            FIELDTERMINATOR = '|',
            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
            ERRORFILE = 'C:\myRubbishData.log'
        )

        select * from #Import
        DROP TABLE #Import
```

Unfortunately using BULK INSERT will not deal with text qualifiers, so you will end up with "ABC" rather than ABC.

Either remove the text qualifiers from the csv file, or run a replace on your table once the data has been imported.

Comment: You could use a format file to specify the text qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

To save you the pain and misery of having to deal with pipes, I would strongly recommend that you process your input file to convert those pipes into commas, and then use SQL Server's built-in capacity to parse CSV into a table.

If you are using Java, replacing the pipes would literally take just one line of code:

```
String line = "\"1\"|\"ABC\"|\"Joe\"|\"Ben\"|\"Boston\"|\"MA\"";
line = line.replaceAll("|", ",");
// then write this line back out to file

BULK INSERT YourTable
FROM 'input.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\SchoolsErrorRows.csv',
    TABLOCK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot work with the `BULK` suggestions (due to rights) you might speed your query up by about 30% with this:

```
SELECT AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(100)') AS ID
      ,AsXml.value('x[2]','varchar(100)') AS ID2
      ,AsXml.value('x[3]','varchar(100)') AS Person
      ,AsXml.value('x[4]','varchar(100)') AS Person2
      ,AsXml.value('x[5]','varchar(100)') AS City
      ,AsXml.value('x[6]','varchar(100)') AS State
FROM #tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SUBSTRING(iddata,2,LEN(iddata)-2),'"|"','</x><x>') + '</x>'  AS XML)) AS a(AsXml)
```